# Creating custom android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a new newbie to android. Just wanna know how could we create the UI layout as similar to the image attached below. I have knowledge of creating basic layouts, please guide me with some sample code examples or any references that might help me.

I have label in the left side of each row and Spinner at right side. **The number of rows to be present on the screen is to be decided dynamically as per the server response. So i cannot hard code the complete view in XML.**

Any kind of help on this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create your layouts as follows:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/llTitle"
           android:background="#ffffff"
           android:gravity="center">
           <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="Title">
     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                   android:background="#FF00FF">
                   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:background="@drawable/customshape"
                                 amdroid:id="@+id/llContainer"/>

                   <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:text="button"
                           android:id/button1"/>
             </LinearLayout>

     </LinearLayout>
```

customshape.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <gradient android:startColor="#SomeGradientBeginColor" android:endColor="#SomeGradientEndColor" 
            android:angle="270"/> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

row.xml
//create rox.xml to contain a textview and a spinner.

in your activity loop to add views to llContainer

```
LinearLayout llContainer=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llContainer);
for(int i0;i<list.size();i++)
{
      LinearLayout llView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
      //set attributes of textview and spinner
      llContainer.addView(llView);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better you take [ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html), design your custom adapter having list item with Label and Spinner.

You just need to pass dynamic values (rows) to your custom adapter.

Comment: Sounds quite interesting. Any examples that i could get on that, which will make my life easy.??

Answer (score 0):

This is an example.Try to customize it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/authnet_auth_buttons"
    android:layout_below="@id/authnet_error_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

```
<Button android:id="@+id/authnet_auth_cancel_button"
android:text="Cancel"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/authnet_error_text"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/authnet_auth_login_button"
android:text="Login"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/authnet_error_text"/>
```

[image]

**For Values you have to use Spinner Widget**

For Dynamic View see 
[How to lay out Views in RelativeLayout programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/laying-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically)

Comment: @Sameer.. The number of rows to be present on the screen is to be decided dynamically as per the server response. So i cannot hard code the complete view in XML.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909062/how-to-align-a-dynamically-create-userinterface-using-relativelayout-in-android for dynamic layouts